# Is confirmatory vs exploratory statistics "induction vs deduction"?

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics, exploratory-data-analysis

[This webpage](http://www.geog.ucsb.edu/~joel/g210_w07/lecture_notes/lect01/oh07_01_2.html) says:

> Inferential Statistics - Deductive Approach
>
> Descriptive Statistics - Inductive Approach

But I doubt it. If I understand correctly,

- Inferential Statistics is "given some data, find the probability model that generates the data", so it is a specific-to-general logic process, and therefore it is induction.
- Descriptive Statistics is "given some data, represent the data in another way", so it is specific-to-specific process of changing data's representation. So it is neither induction or deduction.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add to @Peter Flom's answer, it is worth defining the other terms that were used:

*Deductive reasoning:*  Derive conclusions or predictions about specific cases from fundamental rules or theories.

*Inductive reasoning:*  Derive universal rules or theories from observation of many cases.

Inferential statistics use both inductive and deductive reasoning.  You are trying to establish rules about the behaviour of a system based on evidence, but you are testing models against probability theories derived deductively (i.e., probability distributions in parametric models or the combinatorics that are the basis of non-parametric models).

Descriptive statistics don't really qualify as "reasoning" in my book.  Saying the average of something is *x* and the standard deviation is *s* isn't any more of an argument than saying the colour of something is blue.  You're describing what you have in front of you, not drawing any conclusions beyond it.

Answer (score 19):

I don't think either the web-page or your statements are correct. I'd rather stick with more straightforward descriptions:

Inferential statistics: Given a sample, what can we say about the population from which it was drawn?

Descriptive statistics: Given a sample, what can we say about the sample?

Both can be used as part of inductive or deductive reasoning - the type of reasoning is not supplied by the statistics.