# Does confirmatory = inferential, and exploratory = descriptive analysis / statistics?

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics, terminology, exploratory-data-analysis

Reading [this webpage](http://www.geog.ucsb.edu/~joel/g210_w07/lecture_notes/lect01/oh07_01_2.html), I wonder:

- Are confirmatory analysis / statistics and inferential  analysis / statistics the same concept?
- Are exploratory  analysis / statistics and descriptive  analysis / statistics the same concept?

Comment: I can see an argument that inferential statistics ought only be used for confirmatory analyses, but I don't think we should equate descriptive statistics & EDA (certainly descriptive stats are part of / important for EDA, though).

Comment: This could be more usefully combined with your earlier question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84081/is-confirmatory-vs-exploratory-statistics-induction-vs-deduction

Comment: @gung: Thanks! Could you please explain the definitions/meanings of the four?